# Reexecute the installation from the uninstall section NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I have a NSIS code that install a program , in .onInit I check if an older version did exist and uninstall it if the user click on OK button, I want that once the uninstallation finish the installation re execute again, I try to call `.onInit` in `un.onUninstSuccess` function but it didn't accept it since `un.` function accepts only `un.` function.
Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to do. When you start the uninstaller, you start another process (typically `uninstall.exe`) so you cannot just jump from it to the installer.

What you can do is:

- check if the previous version is present
- if so, start its unistall.exe while waiting for the subprocess to complete
- once you are back in the installer, continue your installation

A usual way to call the uninstaller from the setup is

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninstaller.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR'
```

Comment: Thank you @Seki that's it, I've just been writing an answer and you posted yours, anyway after checking for existing version I run `ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\uninst.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR'` and then the function proceeds as there is not an installed version, thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

probably not the cleanest solution, but there's a [combined un/installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/CombinedUnInstaller) example on the nsis wiki